PrimeNG, InputOtp cant change values of already filled input
I'm using the p-inputOtp component from PrimeNG for OTP input. I've noticed that I can change values until three out of four boxes are filled, but once all four boxes are filled, I can't modify the input anymore. Is there a way to allow changes even after all four boxes are filled?
the code:
`   
<p-inputOtp
class="mt-2 gap-6"
[(ngModel)]="value"
name="otp"
style=""
[integerOnly]="true"
[autofocus]="true"
></p-inputOtp>
`

in this case I can click on the number 2 and change it

but in this case I cant change any number unless I press delete


You can overwrite the inputs with templates
there you should then be able to access keydown and overwrite the value
